# A property of an open cover

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in S}$ be an open cover for a regular topological space $X$.
 The family $\{A_i\}_{i\in S}$ is called locally finite if for every point $x\in X$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that the set
$\{s\in S : U \cap A_s\neq \emptyset\}$ is finite.

Let the family $\{A_i\}_{i\in S}$ have the property that every point of $X$ is contained in only finitely many of $A_i'$s. Can we deduce that the family $\{A_i\}_{i\in S}$ is locally finite?

Comment: Could you please clarify the standalone $A$ in $\{s \in S : U \cap A \not = \emptyset \}$? It's not appeared before.

Comment: Compare the definitions of [paracompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space) and [metacompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacompact_space).

Answer (score 7):

In other words, you're asking if a *point-finite* open cover is locally finite. For a simple counterexample, take $X=\mathbb R,$ and the open cover $\mathcal A=\{\mathbb R,(\frac12,1),(\frac13,\frac12),(\frac14,\frac13),\dots\}.$

Comment: Beause a nbhd of the point $0$.......+1

Comment: I gave you a +1 . That means I gave an up-vote. Doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer bof.  Is the inverse true, that is , if a locally finite space is point - finite?

Comment: Of course a locally finite cover is point-finite. Consider the contrapositive: if the cover is not point-finite, some point $x$ belongs to infinitely many members of the cover, and then every neighborhood of $x$ meets infinitely many members of the cover, so it's not locally finite.